# From a list, how to Print from certain string to certain string

Tags: python

I want to print the Strings in a list.

For example, if my list contains like below, I would like to print the strings between Deer to Crazy, but not Deer and crazy.

['black', 'white', 'Deer', 'Blue', 'More', 'Crazy']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

```
my_list = ['black', 'white', 'Deer', 'Blue', 'More', 'Crazy']
print(*my_list[my_list.index('Deer') + 1: my_list.index('Crazy')])
```

output:

```
Blue More
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `index()` in order to find the indices of the strings you are looking for.
Knowing the indexes you can print the desired strings:

```
my_list = ['black', 'white', 'Deer', 'Blue', 'More', 'Crazy']
print(my_list[my_list.index('Deer') + 1:my_list.index('Crazy')])
```

The output is:

```
['Blue', 'More']
```